# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable after printing a calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that uses a class to calculate the circumference of an ellipse.  I have checked my parenthesies, I have declared my object, but the a type error keeps on coming up and I do not know why.

When I run it, it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace.py", line 16, in <module>
    value.Ramanujans()
  File "C:\workspace.py", line 8, in Ramanujans
    print(math.pi() * 3 * (self.x + self.y) - math.sqrt((3 * self.x + self.y) * (self.x + 3 * self.y)))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

If someone could give a pointer, whether it be that I am not using the class function properly or have not done the arithmetic correctly, that would be lovely.

Comment: `math.pi` is a float, you should call it (i.e use `()`), just drop the parentheses after `math.pi`.

Comment: This works perfectly @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Thank you very much.  If you post that solution as an answer I fill flag it as an answer

Comment: @This doesn't make much sense as a class...

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard solved the problem.  The next time you hit something like this, try breaking your complex expression into single-operation assignment commands.  That will show the problem quickly, saving you the time to post the problem.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am just beginning to learn how a class works.  I figured that It would be senseless doing a calculation as a class, This is helping me make sense of how a class behaves.

Comment: @Prune Will do!

Comment: Damn, you *shouldn't* call it, what a silly typo. It's okay, another answer came and said the same thing :-)

Comment: @vipers356 not relevant to your question, but you should not clutter up your root directory with user files e.g. File "C:\workspace.py"

Comment: @JohnMachin I rewrote the directory in the error.  No worries.  The file is not in the root directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is quite telling: `math.pi` is a `float` (just a number), not a function. `math.pi()` tells python to call a function called `math.pi`, but since `math.pi` is not callable, an error is thrown. Drop the parentheses and you should be fine.